# Oracle Client and ODP.NET version compatibility

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, odp.net, oracle19c, oracle.manageddataaccess

We have upgraded Oracle to 19C and also upgraded the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package to 19.6. However, when we try to open our application on Oracle database 12 then it is showing error, as some machines still has Oracle 12 (Old) database. 
can someone please share the Oracle Data Provider (ODP.Net) compatibility details with Oracle Clients?

Comment: Have a look at this: [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) I am really surprised if they would not be compatible, what is the error messages you get?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your prompt reply, I looked at provided link but it is asking 'Support Identifier' which is i don`t have. I got error message:
"Error description is ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

Comment: For `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` no need to have oracle client. Just ODAC

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not indicate any incompatibility. Looks like the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver does not find your `tnsnames.ora` file

Have a look at [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/InstallManagedConfig.html#GUID-29A85CBD-948D-4C9F-A89D-A96A99EFF2D7)

- Did you define a `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable?
- Did you define `TNS_ADMIN` in your Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\OraClient19Home1` resp. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Oracle\OraClient19Home1_32bit`?

  Documentation states that Registry is not read but for verion 19 I am not sure about that
- Did you define the `TNS_ADMIN` in .NET config file?

  The easiest way to set it there would be the `OraProvCfg.exe` tool. Would be similar to this:

For 64-bit:

```
c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\ODP.NET\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:C:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:C:\oracle\network\admin
```

For 32-bit:

```
c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\ODP.NET\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:C:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:C:\oracle\network\admin
```

Comment: I have tried all above options but didn't work. FYI- if i downgrade the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package to 12.2 from 19.6 then it is working on Oracle database 12c but not worked on Oracle database 19c

Comment: What about the .NET config files? The `TNS_ADMIN` entries are version specific.

Comment: Yes, i have defined TNS_Admin in .Net config file as well.

Comment: Do you use alias resolution from Oracle Name server (i.e. using `ldap.ora`)?