# The underlying provider failed on Open error in with a C# app using oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I have a C# app that is written with Entity Framework utilizing two DB entities (Oracle)... However, I'm getting the following error on my test server...

Help would be appreciated...

Error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. and Details:
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
>   ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified --->
>   OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): ORA-12154:
>   TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified at
>   OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..ctor(String TNSAlias,
>   SqlNetOraConfig SNOConfig, Hashtable ObTnsHT, String instanceName,
>   ConnectionOption CO) at
>   OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Resolve(String tnsAlias,
>   ConnectionOption& CO) at
>   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.ResolveTnsAlias(ConnectionString
>   cs, Object OC) at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString
>   cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria,
>   String instanceName) at
>   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString
>   csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
>   at
>   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString
>   csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
>   at
>   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString
>   cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword,
>   SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection
>   connRefForCriteria) at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)

Comment: Does this provide any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646800/oracleexception-0x80004005-when-connecting-to-oracle-database

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052285/oracle-client-and-odp-net-version-compatibility/60055566#60055566